# Unity Physics Engine Collisions Problem with walls

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I am having a rather weird thing happening in a game I am trying to make and was wondering if anyone else in the community has had this occur before.

So I have 4 cubes as walls. Top, bottom, left and right. They have Box Colliders and Rigidbodies.

I have a ball which is a 2d sprite with a sphere collider on it.

If they wall all intersect their neighbor then the collision works.

The problem is when I separate the walls so there is a gap between their neighbors then the ball doesn't bounce top and bottom and it will just go right through the left and right walls as if the weren't there.

Has anyone else had this happen to them?

Here is a screenshot of the walls:

[image]

And the inspector for them:
[image]

Comment: It seems like you are doing something wrong. Maybe you moved the walls in +/-z direction while seperating them. Did you check that. Also please share screenshot of the Editor with components visible. It would help us to understand what is wrong

Comment: First of all no need for Rigidbodies on static objects like walls, floor. When it comes to your problem it might be related to scales and positions of your objects or your physics settings.

Comment: They all share the same z-position, rotation, and scale. I will look into the resulting position when moving them.

Comment: @Dave It looks like you pointing out that I don't need a rigid body on static elements seemed to fix my issue!

Comment: Great, in general use Rigidbodies only with elements that you want to move with physics engine.